# Regarding Webservice and its funcitons

Tags: php

i want to learn how to write web service in php.. I'm new to it i want to know how to start and where to start give some tips please. i want to know about Web Service how to use it and how to make use in PHP.

Comment: You know how to program?

Comment: i want to know how to program web service in php.. can u explain with any simple example to start..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by saying "Web Service"?

Try to read this article: [Create a Basic Web Service Using PHP, MySQL, XML, and JSON](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

I hope it will be a good start.

Comment: i want to know how to program web service in php.. can u explain with any simple example to start..